# Angular / Jasmine fails to inject controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm having trouble getting started using Jasmine and AngularJS. I've tried to create a minimal example, largely derived from the angular docs:

I have a module and a controller in testme.js:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    let cont = function($scope) {
        $scope.data = 99;
    };
    let app = angular.module('Test', []);
    app.controller('Cont', cont);
}());
```

I have a test TestSpec.js

```
"use strict";
console.log('launching test...');
describe('Test a test', function(){
    console.log('in describe...');
    
    beforeEach(angular.module('Test'));
    
    it('should create a number', inject(function($controller){
        let scope = {};

        console.log('in test...');
        let ctrl = $controller('Cont', {$scope:scope}); // fails here
        console.log('got controller...');
        expect(scope.data).toBe(99);
        console.log('test completed...');
    }));
});
```

And a SpecRunner.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="Test">
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.css">
        <script src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
        <script src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
        <script src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.4.1/boot.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/angular-mocks.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/testme.js"></script>    
        <script src="test/TestSpec.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body data-ng-controller="Cont">
        <h1>Value is {{data}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems like it starts up, and I get the messages

launching test...
in describe...
in test...

but it fails trying to execute the line I marked as // fails here, in TestSpec.js. This tells me that I'm not managing to retrieve the controller. Needless to say, I don't understand why (there are many questions on this topic, but they all seem not applicable here, as far as I can see).

Oh, and in case it's relevant, I'm using Angular 1.5:

[image: Here's the screenshot of the various errors.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here

```
beforeEach(angular.module('Test'));
```

It should be [`module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module).

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new scope as the child of `$rootScope`. Replace the line to create scope with below in your test:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('Test'));

it('should create a number', inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
    let scope = $rootScope.$new();

    console.log('in test...');
    let ctrl = $controller('Cont', {$scope:scope});
    console.log('got controller...');
    expect(scope.data).toBe(99);
    console.log('test completed...');
}));
```

Also you should not use `angular.module` but `angular.mock.module` to refer to modules

Comment: As the answer from estus, it seems that the $rootScope isn't critical to making my example work. I'll try to study more and find out what difference that might make in the big scheme of things, or perhaps you can add a couple of words?

Also, what's the difference between angular.mock.module, and plain module (which is what estus indicated, and actually what the angular docs gave before I messed it up)? Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You're not injecting your controller dependencies, and your structure is a little off. You don't need to assign block level variables.

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module('Test', [])
    .controller('Cont', cont);

    Cont.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function cont($scope) {
        $scope.data = 99;
    };
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that doesn't actually change anything [I copied/pasted that over the top of my version]. Two questions (because I don't see how it would change anything.

 - First, I understand that the Cont.$inject _should_ be irrelevant in this test because I'm specifically not minifying my code (note that the $scope injection succeeds in the template HTML)
 - Second, I took a two step process to assigning the controller using the intermediate variable. Again, I don't see any function difference with your "create the module and immediately chain the controller". Yessno??

Comment: Indeed, the minification protection thing with $inject would be normal for "real" code. Hopefully there's some other difference we can find. Thanks again for trying!

Comment: I might also note that a great deal of Angular testing is done with Karma as the runner. It might be worth checking out.